# Vim Search/replace: what do I need to escape?

Tags: vim, replace

I'm trying to search and replace `$data['user']` for `$data['sessionUser']`.

However, no matter what search string I use, I always get a "pattern not found" as the result of it.

So, what would be the correct search string? Do I need to escape any of these characters?
`:%s/$data['user']/$data['sessionUser']/g`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
:%s/\$data\[\'user\'\]/$data['sessionUser']/g
```

I did not test this, but I guess it should work.

Comment: You don't need the escapes in the replace part.

Answer (score 11):

Here's a list of all special search characters you need to escape in Vim: `^$.*[~)+/\

Comment: Thanks for this concise piece of knowledge!

Comment: You need to escape `)` and `+` too

Comment: as well as `/`.

Comment: What you might miss, at least I ran into this: `<` and `>` like in xml tags do not need to be escaped.

Comment: Why do I need to escape + character when using a regex in vim? I supposed I need to escape only when looking for +

Comment: how about backslash?  I had to escape \ also

Answer (score 4):

Search and replace in vim is almost identical to [`sed`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed), so use the same escapes as you would with that:

```
:%s/\$data\['user'\]/$data['session']/g
```

Note that you only really need to escape special characters in the search part (the part between the first set of `//`s). The only character you need to escape in the replace part is the escape character `\` itself (which you're not using here).

Comment: Interesting information about the second `//`. Thanks for it.

Answer (score 4):

There's nothing wrong with with the answers given, but you can do this:

```
:%s/$data\['\zsuser\ze']/sessionUser/g
```

`\zs` and `\ze` can be used to delimit the part of the match that is affected by the replacement.
You don't need to escape the `$` since it's the at the start of the pattern and can't match an EOL here. And you don't need to escape the `]` since it doesn't have a matching starting `[`. However there's certainly no harm in escaping these characters if you can't remember all the rules. See :help pattern.txt for the full details, but don't try to digest it all in one go!

If you want to get fancy, you can do:

```
:%s/$data\['\zsuser\ze']/session\u&/g
```

`&` refers to the entire matched text (delimited by `\zs` and `\ze` if present), so it becomes 'user' in this case. The `\u` when used in a replacement string makes the next character upper-case. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The `[` char has a meaning in regex. It stands for [character ranges](http://vimregex.com/#ranges). The `$` char has a meaning too. It stands for [end-line anchor](http://vimregex.com/#anchors). So you have to escape a lot of things. I suggest you to try a little plugin like [this](https://github.com/bronson/vim-visual-star-search) or this [one](https://github.com/thinca/vim-visualstar) and use a visual search.

Comment: I was really looking for an easier option for searching. I'll get to know more about the built in search and replace, but it's probable that I'll try one of those you showed me. Thanks.